# Symfony + Redis - how to search by tag

Tags: symfony, redis, symfony-3.1, symfony-3.2

As of version 3.x Symfny [supports Redis as a cache](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-cache-component).

It is working fine, but only if I want to get some data from cache like:

```
$redis = $this->get('cache.app');

$cached = $redis->getItem('video#32');
$data = $cached->get();

if (!$cached->isHit()) {
    $cached->set([
        'users' => [
            $userId => [
                'username' => $userName,
                'refresh' => new \DateTime()
            ]
        ]
    ])->tag('stack, overflow, symfony, support');
    $redis->save($cached);
}
```

Is it possible to search/find all rows from cache with tag `stack` and `support`? I was searching for it in the symfony docs but there is no information about it. If it is not possible, when and how I should use tags if I cannot use them for searching?

btw: there is [information](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-tagged-cache) that we need to use `TaggedCacheItemInterface` but several days later it was [dropped](http://symfony.com/blog/a-week-of-symfony-502-8-14-august-2016) [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/5cc9ed2048e8a73a31d681fcc23d4997fe83e7a0)